# How to avoid repeating when conditionals in ansible?

Tags: ansible

I have this playbook:

```
---
- name: Test
  hosts: localhost

  tasks:
    - name: Ansible grep pattern with ignore_errors example
      shell: "grep 'authorization' /tmp/junk.test"
      register: grep_output
      ignore_errors: true

    - name: Output debug grep_output
      debug:
        var: grep_output
        verbosity: 0
      shell: "echo 'Hello!'"
      when: grep_output.failed
```

When I run it I get this error:

```
ERROR! conflicting action statements: debug, shell
```

So I have to rewrite the playbook to look like this:

```
---
- name: Test
  hosts: localhost

  tasks:
    - name: Ansible grep pattern with ignore_errors example
      shell: "grep 'authorization' /tmp/junk.test"
      register: grep_output
      ignore_errors: true

    - name: Output debug grep_output
      debug:
        var: grep_output
        verbosity: 0
      when: grep_output.failed

    - name: Echo hello
      shell: "echo 'Hello!'"
      when: grep_output.failed
```

So I am repeating the `when: grep_output.failed`.  Is there a better way of writing the above playbook?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [block statement](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_blocks.html). It allows you to group modules and use a single `when` statement for the entire block.
This should work:

```
---
- name: Test
  hosts: localhost

  tasks:
    - name: Ansible grep pattern with ignore_errors example
      shell: "grep 'authorization' /tmp/junk.test"
      register: grep_output
      ignore_errors: true

    - block:
      - name: Output debug grep_output
        debug:
          var: grep_output
          verbosity: 0

      - name: Echo hello
        shell: "echo 'Hello!'"
      when: grep_output.failed
```

Comment: That does it! Except I needed to change `- block:` to `block:`.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. It's weird though, just tried it and it ran successfully. Did you run this exact playbook?

Comment: No I didn't run that exact same playbook. I removed the `-` from `block:`. I guess it works either way.

Comment: @AlassaneNdiaye as a side note, when you apply `when` to a block, it'll still evaluate the when for each task in the block.